# i am unable to sync my 2007 outlook using "salesforceforoutlook.exe" from salesforce.com

Tags: administration, developer, outlook, salesforce-for-outlook

i have downloaded from the desktop administration "salesforceforoutlook.exe" & installed it. But it did not install 100%. showed the error as "office2007-kb2584063" missing for OutLook 2007. Then i installed "office2007-kb2584063" to my outlook 2007. & tried to reinstall "salesforceforoutlook.exe" but it did not install at all. Help me to intall salesforce to my outlook 2007

Answer (score 2):

Did you do this?
[Salesforce for Outlook wont install](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gkrUAAQ)